# Using removeall to remove spaces between brackets() and numbers

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, replaceall

I am trying to achieve something like this

> Input -> ( 10 )

I want output as `(10)`

I want to eliminate space between brackets and numbers in Java using `String.removeAll()`,
[Note: Only one space is there]

Unable to write regular expression for this.

I tried:

```
String s = "( 10 )";
Sysout(s.removeAll("\\( [0-9]+ \\) )" , "\\([0-9]+)"));
```

But its not working

Comment: Do you want to remove whitespace characters in general or only between brackets?

Comment: Did my solution below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine for you.

```
    String s = "( 10 )";

    s=s.replaceFirst("\\( ", "\\(");
    s=s.replaceFirst(" \\)", "\\)");
    System.out.println(s);
```

Ouput:

```
(10)
```

Comment: There can be many brackets in my string. I want to replace spaces only when bracket contains numbers.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide some more inputs and outputs like you did for ( 10 ) ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

String input="( 10 )";

System.out.println(input.replaceAll("\\(\\s+" , "(").replaceAll("\\s+\\)", ")"));

//replaceAll("\\(\\s+" , "(")  --will remove spaces present after (

//replaceAll("\\s+\\)", ")")  --will remove spaces present before )

Comment: my requirements are specific. I want to remove spaces from numbers inside brackets having only single space. There should be no space b/w digits

Comment: Please find updated answer and let me know if it answer your question.